# HIVE CREATE TABLE sematicException 0:0

Tags: hive, hql

**HI, all :**
i am newbie at hive, i got this error when i was creating a table using "select from " syntax,
**my input is as following:**

```
`hive>create table longyuan_web.tmp_recent_week_data_cookies as 
 select u from longyuan_web.ods_mbw_user_pv where dt>='2018-07-19' 
 and dt<='2018-07-25'and  platform='31' 
 and u is not null and length(u)>=32
 and os='ios' group by u`
```

**i get this error:**
`FAILED: SemanticException 0:0 Error creating temporary folder on: hdfs://hadoop-bd-ns01/hive/warehouse/longyuan_web.db. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE`'

i am pretty sure i am on the right cluster and the original table is also on this  cluster
**what this 'TOK_TMP_FILE'?** 
**thank you so much**!!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the issue is **user doesn't have access to write** to **longyuan_web** database.

Please check that you have correct permissions and then try to execute then execute CTAS again.

Jira ticket addressing same exact issue is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11427)

Comment: thanks a lot Shu,you are right,i create temp table in  another database and it works

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

(I assume Your select query runs good as stand-alone)

You have read access in longyuan_web db. But not write access.

Work around is... 
Try to create the table in some other db where you have write access, like....

```
 `hive>create table **xxx_web**.tmp_recent_week_data_cookies as select u from longyuan_web.ods_mbw_user_pv where dt>='2018-07-19' and dt<='2018-07-25'and platform='31' and u is not null and length(u)>=32 and os='ios' group by u` as select u from longyuan_web.ods_mbw_user_pv where dt>='2018-07-19' and dt<='2018-07-25'and platform='31' and u is not null and length(u)>=32 and os='ios' group by u`
```

Where xxx_web is the Db where you have write access.