# Hive query error encountered near token TOK_TMP_FILE

Tags: hive

I get a long error. Below is the first few lines

> TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=3, infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 0:0 Error creating temporary folder on: maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/wh_db.db. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE':28:27", 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:388', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:193', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:276',`

According to this thread the error while creating table based on a select query is because the user does not have write permission to the db where the user is connected. 
[HIVE CREATE TABLE sematicException 0:0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535822/hive-create-table-sematicexception-00)

I'm running my query from a db where the user has write access. So in below query, user has `write` permission to `db2` and `read` permissions to `db1` and `db3`

Query

```
use db2;

CREATE TABLE tbl123 AS 
    SELECT FROM db1.tbl1 t1 
    INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key 
    INNER JOIN db3.tbl3 t3 ON t1.key2 = t3.key;
```

Also when the query is executed by logging into a shell console, it runs fine. But when run from a program using `python-pyhive`, this error occurs. I am using below config to run queries. With `default` and `tez` engine, the query executed successfully from shell. Only using `pyhive` I get this error

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 2):

please check user has permission to create temporary folder in the location.